# NOOBS on Raspberry Pi 3 not starting

Tags: noobs

I changed `/boot/config.xml` because I had error with `sudo i2cdetect 1` command.
Now NOOBS cannot start.

How i can edit `/boot/config.xml` on SD card with Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Just mount your sdcard and open mounted drive.

It will be boot partition with **config.txt** (not *.xml*).

More about **config.txt** you can read at: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md

Comment: Thanks Huczu for answer. I am trying Ext2fsd and Ext2IFS on Windows 7 without success...so i uninstalled and re-install NOOBS RASBIAN which fix it.

Comment: You don't need any extension to mount boot partition. It's FAT32 partition. You will see it normally.